# explicit cast on XAttribute value

Tags: c#, .net, casting, linq-to-xml

I recently wrote a piece of code that looked a bit like this:

```
IEnumerable<DTO.Employee> xEmployee =
    from e in xDoc.Descendants("Employee")
    where int.Parse(e.Attribute("Id").Value) == emp.Id
    select new DTO.Employee
    {
        Id = (int)e.Attribute("Id"),
        LastName = (string)e.Element("LastName"),
        FirstName = (string)e.Element("FirstName"),
        Email = (string)e.Element("Email")
    };
```

However, I am confused about the casting to an int in the where clause. First, I'd written something like

```
where (int)(e.Attribute("Id").Value) == emp.Id
```

which didn't compile.
Why can I do a explicit cast on (e.Attribute("Id")), but can 't I do this on (e.Attribute("Id").Value)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the explicit operator overloads of the [XAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.op_explicit.aspx) class.

```
public static explicit operator int(XAttribute attribute);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an [explicit conversion from `XAttribute` to `int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358993.aspx) - but there's no explicit conversion from `string` (the type of `XAttribute.Value`) to `int`.